# CS1061 From PSXEffect Asset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Getting Errors "Assets\PSXEffects\Example\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(26,7): error CS1061: 'CharacterController' does not contain a definition for 'Move' and no accessible extension method 'Move' accepting a first argument of type 'CharacterController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

and

"Assets\PSXEffects\Example\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(25,11): error CS1061: 'CharacterController' does not contain a definition for 'isGrounded' and no accessible extension method 'isGrounded' accepting a first argument of type 'CharacterController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I'm Very Very new to coding and tried some other janky bootleg solutions but they either just made it worse or caused other issues. I renamed the "CharacterController cc;" to "CharacterControllerA" which caused the error

"...PlayerMovement.cs(11,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CharacterControllera' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" ~to happen. pls help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public Light dirLight;
    public GameObject museumText;

    private CharacterController cc;
    private PSXEffects psx;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        psx = FindObjectOfType<PSXEffects>();
        dirLight.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        museumText.SetActive(false);
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        cc.Move((transform.forward * Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") + transform.right * Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")).normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (!cc.isGrounded) {
            cc.Move(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * Physics.gravity.y);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.transform.tag == "DemoRoom") {
            ToggleDemoMode(true);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        if (other.transform.tag == "DemoRoom") {
            ToggleDemoMode(false);
        }
    }

    public void ToggleDemoMode(bool enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            RenderSettings.fog = false;
            psx.favorRed = 0;
            psx.maxDarkness = 0;
            psx.resolutionFactor = 1;
            psx.polygonalDrawDistance = -1;
            psx.dithering = false;
            psx.colorDepth = 24;
            dirLight.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            museumText.SetActive(true);
            psx.UpdateProperties();
        } else {
            RenderSettings.fog = true;
            psx.favorRed = 1;
            psx.maxDarkness = 10;
            psx.resolutionFactor = 2;
            psx.polygonalDrawDistance = 30.61f;
            psx.dithering = false;
            psx.colorDepth = 24;
            dirLight.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            museumText.SetActive(false);
            psx.UpdateProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had an import settings file for a different character controller i had been messing with, deleting this file caused the errors to go away! I figured it out by opening a new project and the asset store package was working just fine!